# How to handle relative paths in node.js / express?

Tags: node.js, express, lighttpd

I've written a website in node.js and express. Now I configured lighttpd to use the node.js server with an subdirectory:

```
$HTTP["url"] =~ "^/app/" {
  proxy.server  = ( "" => ( (
                              "host" => "127.0.0.1",
                              "port" => 3000
                            ) )
                  )
}
```

When I open `http://localhost/app/` I get error 404 because I wrote something like this:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res){
  res.render('index');
});
```

Is there a better way as modifying these lines like:

```
var relPath = '/app';

app.get(relPath + '/', function (req, res){
  res.render('index');
});
```

?

Comment: `app.use('/app', app.router);` may do the trick.

Comment: It does in fact do the trick, though I'm not running behind a proxy.

Comment: The proxy shouldn't matter as long it doesn't munge the path.

Comment: @RyanOlds Your comment should be the accepted answer!

Comment: any chance of getting a full code block on how the `app.use('/app', app.router);` fits into the above example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Ryan commented the solution is:

```
app.use('/app', app.router);
```

If you use e.g. express.static or express.favicon you have to tell app.use the path also:

```
app.use('/app', express.favicon(__dirname + '/public/images/favicon.ico'));
app.use('/app', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Remember to write '/app' before each internal link you set in your html.