# AWS EC2 port opened, but still not accessible

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-ec2

I have port TCP 3000 enabled, it even shows enabled under the EC2 security settings.

Although I can not telnet into my server via that port, I'm getting `Could not open connection to the host, on port 3000: Connect failed`.

I'm running an Ubuntu 12.04 AWS EC2 Micro instance in Oregon.

I'm running apache on the server to host http(s) (80/443) traffic and am trying to host an additional app through port 3000 via nodejs express.

Here is my Apache sites-enabled file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerAdmin name@domain.com
 ServerName www.domain.com
 ServerAlias www.domain.com

 DocumentRoot /var/www/

 ProxyRequests off

 <Proxy *>
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
 </Proxy>

 <Location />
      ProxyPass http://localhost:80/
      ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:80/
 </Location>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerAdmin name@domain.com
 ServerName lobby.domain.com
 ServerAlias lobby.domain.com

 <Proxy *>
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
 </Proxy>

 <Location />
      ProxyPass http://localhost:3000/
      ProxyPassReverse http://lobby.domain.com/
 </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what you want on your reverse proxy configs:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerAdmin name@domain.com
 ServerName www.domain.com
 ServerAlias www.domain.com

 DocumentRoot /var/www/

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin name@domain.com
  ServerName lobby.domain.com
  ServerAlias lobby.domain.com

 <Proxy *>
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
 </Proxy>

 <Location />
     ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:3000/
     ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:3000/
 </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

Make sure you enable the apache proxy modules, from the command line:

```
a2enmod proxy
a2enmod proxy_connect
a2enmod proxy_http
a2enmod proxy_balancer
service apache2 restart
```

Comment: I only want lobby.domain.com to use :3000, all other traffic should use :80

Comment: You need to specify that on your question.  Try the change that I made, You don't need a proxy for `*:80` since apache is already listening on port 80

Comment: it still pushes lobby.domain.com traffic to domain.com:80

Comment: if I remove the lobby.comain.com from the <VirtualHost> tag, it directs forward fine. But links try to direct the client to "http://127.0.0.1:3000/link" instead of "http://lobby.domain.com/link". Any suggestions? I feel like you've gotten me really close!

Comment: The problem is with your node app router configuration. It's using a full http path instead of just a relative path. You can find more information here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11379482/how-to-handle-relative-paths-in-node-js-express

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are binding your application on `0.0.0.0` instead of `127.0.0.1` or `localhost`. It sounds like your application is not listening to IP addresses outside of the server.

(Also make sure your node.js application is running too)

To listed on `0.0.0.0` you need to so something like this in your application:

```
var app = connect().use(connect.static('public')).listen(3000, "0.0.0.0");
```

Comment: `Express server listening on port 3000` it's running. this is a managed package that I downloaded. How do I configure the binding through node.js?

Comment: app.configure(function(){
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.favicon());
  app.use(express.logger('dev'));
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.cookieParser());
  app.use(express.session(
    { store: new SqliteStore()
    , secret: '******'
  }));
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
});

Comment: I don't see it listening to local host only. Is there anywhere else I'd check?

Comment: And netstat -taupen results in : `User       Inode       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN   `

Comment: Well can you connect to it from localhost first ?  have you tried `curl http://localhost:3000` ?

Comment: Rico, I don't use connect, it's using express. Also I can curl locally, but not from the domain/IP: `curl: (7) couldn't connect to host`

Comment: I've also updated my apache routing above too, maybe that's causing the issue.

Comment: Are you doing reverse proxy with Apache ?

Comment: yes and I think I'm doing it wrong, I think that's my issue. Updating my original file

Comment: Check my other answer :)